# Shortcut key for changing code cell to markdown cell in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Kind of silly, but is there a shortcut key to change a code cell to markdown cell?
To place a markdown cell, I have to insert a cell, then go to the toolbar menu (below the main menu bar), and then select "Markdown" instead of "Code".

Comment: And as a useful reminder, pressing **H** (as for **H**elp) key while in command mode (press **Esc** to enter command mode) will show all available shortcut keys.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Press <kbd>M</kbd> whilst in command mode (highlight around the selected cell should be blue, not green), use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch to command mode and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch back to edit mode.

So, if you're editing a cell, the key presses to change the cell to a markdown cell are <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can look up all the Jupyter notebook keyboard commands by pressing the keyboard icon in the toolbar. You can also edit your keyboard shortcuts by going to `Help > Edit Keyboard Shortcuts`

Comment: Thanks Louise. I did not expect it to be this simple. Next I started pressing other keys one after another. I found, Pressing R changes this to Raw, Y to Code. Press P and you can see all of the short cut groupings!!!

Comment: Any shortcut for the same task in JupyterLab? `Enter` and `M` doesn't work in JupyterLab sadly...

Comment: @steven Are you sure? I'm pretty sure they aimed to keep the keyboard shortcuts the same across the notebook and Jupyterlab, and it works in my instance - are you going into command mode first by pressing `Esc` first? This should mean there is no more cursor in the cell you're editing. Realistically, the shortcut is just `M`, the `Esc` just puts you into command mode and `Enter` puts you back in edit mode. You can also try searching for the shortcut in `Settings > Advanced Settings Editor > Keyboard Shortcuts`

Comment: No, it won't work in my end. Maybe I missed something? https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4125#issuecomment-481074726

Comment: @steven I'd suggest you open your notebook in a different browser or in incognito mode. It's possible that some browser extension is interfering with the shortcuts. (in my case, the vimium extension on Chrome was causing the issue)

Comment: @tomzx thank you so much man.... Indeed, after disabling vimium, everything works great!

Comment: On JupyterLab (v1.0.2) that's a lowercase `m` not `M`. Uppercase M will merge cells. This is not among the menu options.

Comment: You may use shortcut for Markdown which is "Esc + M" on WIndows

Comment: The answer by Irene Lee answers the question best

Answer (score 54):

[check help on the menu, there is keyboard shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZVi6.png)

select the code cell, press "esc + m ",and it will be a markdown cell.
moreover, from markdown cell to code cell, press " esc + y ".

Comment: Would have loved if it was "esc+c" to change from markdown to code

Comment: Just tried this on a Jupyter Notebook on VSCode and it works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for including the markdown to code binding as well. For some reason the dropdown menu doesn't work / fights me on Firefox, seemingly at random...

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to the required cell and press the `Esc` key on your keyboard followed by the `M` key

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `vim-bindings`, the shortcut changes to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, also in command mode as in @Louise Davies answer.