# How to convert a cell type in Google colab notebook using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Are there any shortcuts to convert the current cell (where my cursor is) from one type to other (code cell -> Text Cell) or vice versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short cut key for markdown cell in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787721/short-cut-key-for-markdown-cell-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @LouiseDavies are the shortcuts definitely the same for colab as for jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> will convert a code cell to a text cell.
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> will convert a text cell to a code cell.

The full list of keyboard shortcuts is available under 'Keyboard shortcuts' in the Tools menu.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Please check the above image and follow it. For more shortcuts follow the tools>keyboard shortcuts in google colab